# Enable Application badge from push notification iOS Swift Xcode 7.3

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a LoginViewController and HomeViewController, in my appdelegate

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

i have

`let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`

it asks when the user launch for first time i.e in login page it recieves push notification and updates icon badge number, I need to ask user permission in home page i.e after login success, so I moved the above code to **homeviewController viewDidLoad()**, it asks for user permission it recieves push notification and local variable is incremented, but the application badge number is not showing, if I move the code to appdelegate

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

it works fine. 
i update badgenumber by

> didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
```

and i reset the badge number in

> applicationDidBecomeActive